# ifstream not pulling any data in

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm working on the code below which performs a binary chop search on a sorted textfile. The text file looks something like this:

Amerse              Gregorina           5465874526370945

Anderson            Bob                 4235838387422002

Legstrong-Cones     Mike                8238742438632892

Currently my getline in my constructor ( for debugging) pulls in the first line of data correctly. However, when i call my findmethod, both a getline and the cs << with variables pull NO DATA in. I tried using pointers and the getLine pulled in nothing as well. I've sorted through StackOverflow and done some googling to help figure this issue at but can't seem to come to a resolotion. Any help/ explanation would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class CardSearch {
protected:
ifstream cs;
public:
int currLength;

CardSearch(string fileName) {
    /* Make sure our file stream opens properly
       pos = current position -> set at 0 to begin
       I use seekg to go to the end of the file and tellg me how many bytes we read to go to the end */

    cs.open(fileName, ios::in);
    if(cs.fail()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string dummy;
    getline(cs,dummy); // debug print 
    cout << dummy << endl;

    cs.seekg(0,ios::end);
    currLength= (int)cs.tellg();
}

string find( string lastN, string firstN) {
    string cardNum;
    string currLast = "!!";
    string currFirst = "!!";
    string dummy;

    while (currLast != lastN && currFirst != firstN) {
        currLength = currLength/2;
        if (lastN > currLast) {
            cs.seekg(currLength, ios::cur); // if the lastName given is > where we are, move forward
        } else {
            cs.seekg((-1 * currLength), ios::cur); // // if the lastName given is < where we are, move backward
        }

        cs >> lastN >> firstN >> cardNum;
        cout << currLast << " " << currFirst << " : " << cardNum << endl;
    }

    return cardNum;
}

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CardSearch instance("StolenNumbers.txt");
    string s = instance.find("Rathbone", "Luke");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your constructor be public?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

1) When `find` starts, your file is at the end, because after you open it, you seek it to the end in order to read the size with `tellg`, but you kep it at the end. Then:

2)

> ```
> if (lastN > currLast) {
>             cs.seekg(currLength, ios::cur); // if the lastName given is > where we are, move forward
>         } else {
>             cs.seekg((-1 * currLength), ios::cur); // // if the lastName given is < where we are, move backward
>         }
> ```

It would have worked if at the first test the `else` applied, but in fact, the if succeeds because you initialize `lastN` to "Rathbone" and currLast to `"!!"`. Hence, you attempt to seek the file further from its end, so it gets stuck at the end, and you wont read anything.

Solution: at the end of your constructor, seek the file to its beginning:

```
cs.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your input; it was very well outlined.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `cs.seekg(0,ios::end);`

You are setting the file pointer to the end of the file. Hence, there is nothing to read further.

Also, it is a good idea to check whether stream extraction worked correctly each time you use it. This is how you do it..

```
if ( ! ( cs >> lastN >> firstN >> cardNum ) );
    CallErrorHandlingCode(); // Throw exception, or print to console, or exit program.
```

Had you written stream extraction like above, you would have caught the bug at run-time.

Comment: Thanks First Jens! I realized my issue. You were right! I was going past the end and should of noticed that. I was doing that call to find out how long the file was initially for future reference. I should of seeked back to the beginning of the file afterwards. I also should have set currLength = cs.tellg(); after I exited the if. Thank you!

Comment: @BitShift Happy to help :)